# Рекурсивный вывод файлов

Tags: linux, terminal

Как в терминале linux рекурсивно вывести содержимое файлов, имя которых начинается на 'c', не используя команду find? Пробовал `cat ./c*` - но этот способ не работает.

Comment: `grep -r` и дальше?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grep -rh '.*' ./c*
```

Ключ -h позволяет не выводить имя файла в начале каждой строки вывода. Если его убрать, то каждая строка вывода будет выглядеть как:

```
file/path/name:output string
```

P.S. кстати, возможно вам пригодиться. Если задать:

```
grep -rl '<pattern>' ./c*
```

То это выведет список имен всех фалов в текущей директории и ниже, начинающихся на 'c' в тексте которых встречается `<pattern>`